# Pointcloud to pcd file with Timestamp in name

Tags: ros, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, image, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Guys,

i use Ubuntu 16.04 with ros kinetic and gazebo 7.0. I have a Gazebo world with  turtlebot in it.

I get some Pointcloud data from /camera/depth/points. Now i want to save this data in pcd files.

I use:

```
rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/camera/depth/points
```

That works well i get some pcd files. Now i want to add the timestamp to the file name is this somehow possible? Or is there something in pcl_ros that support this?

I know that most of the ros topics have a timestamp.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/282926/pointcloud-to-pcd-file-with-timestamp-in-name/) by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 206 on 2018-02-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm confused. By default `pointcloud_to_pcd` should already use the timestamp of the msg as the filename.

See [wiki/pcl_ros - pointcloud_to_pcd](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl_ros#pointcloud_to_pcd).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Baumboon](https://answers.ros.org/users/32033/baumboon/) on 2018-02-16**:
oops i just saw number like 1894000 an so on , i was too nooby to understand this is the timestamp so question is closed thank u .

Sry for my fail

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-02-16**:
Well, it is *a* timestamp. It's not necessarily in a format you'd like though. There is no support for any other timestamp than the unix stamp it uses now.

Note btw that it does support a `prefix` parameter.